# iOS Neon assembler sample questions

Tags: ios, objective-c, assembly, arm, neon

Just trying http://api.madewithmarmalade.com/ExampleArmASM.html and using iOS; the program run if I comment out the loop and the res is printed as 28.  But if not comment it out, it will abend without printing the res.

Any hint why and how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>  
#define ARRAY_SIZE 512  

#if defined __arm__ && defined __ARM_NEON__

static int computeSumNeon(const int a[])
{
// Computes the sum of all elements in the input array
int res = 0;
asm(".align 4          \n\t"  //dennis warning avoiding
    "vmov.i32 q8, #0          \n\t"  //clear our accumulator register
    "mov r3, #512             \n\t"  //Loop condition n = ARRAY_SIZE
//        ".loop1:                  \n\t" // No loop add 0-7 works as 28
    "vld1.32 {d0, d1, d2, d3}, [%[input]]! \n\t" //load 8 elements into d0, d1, d2, d3 = q0, q1
    "pld [%[input]]           \n\t" // preload next set of elements
    "vadd.i32 q8, q0, q8      \n\t" // q8 += q0
    "vadd.i32 q8, q1, q8      \n\t" // q8 += q1
    "subs r3, r3, #8          \n\t" // n -= 8
//        "bne .loop1               \n\t" // n == 0?
    "vpadd.i32 d0, d16, d17   \n\t" // d0[0] = d16[0] + d16[1], d0[1] = d17[0] + d17[1]
    "vpaddl.u32 d0, d0        \n\t" // d0[0] = d0[0] + d0[1]
    "vmov.32 %[result], d0[0] \n\t"
    : [result] "=r" (res) , [input] "+r" (a)
    :
    : "q0", "q1", "q8", "r3");
return res;
}


#else

static int computeSumNeon(const int a[])
{
    int i, res = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
        res += a[i];
}

#endif


...

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
//int* inp;
int inp[ARRAY_SIZE];
//posix_memalign((void**)&inp, 64, ARRAY_SIZE*sizeof(int)); // Align to cache line size (64bytes on a cortex A8)
// Initialise the array with consecutive integers.
int i;
for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
{
    inp[i] = i;
}
for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
{
    printf("%i,", inp[i]);
}
printf("\n\n sum 0-7:%i\n", 0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7);

int res = 0;

res = computeSumNeon(inp);


printf("res NEO :%i\n", res);

// free(inp); // error pointer being free was not allocated !!!

UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
splitViewController.delegate = self;
return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
...
```

==== assembly code generated

```
    .align  1
    .code   16                      @ @computeSumNeon
    .thumb_func _computeSumNeon
_computeSumNeon:
Lfunc_begin3:
    .loc    18 133 0 is_stmt 1      @ ...
    .cfi_startproc
@ BB#0:
    sub sp, #8
    movs    r1, #0
    str r0, [sp, #4]
    .loc    18 135 9 prologue_end   @ ...
Ltmp18:
    str r1, [sp]
    .loc    18 136 5                @ ...
    ldr r0, [sp, #4]
    @ InlineAsm Start
    .align  4
    vmov.i32    q8, #0x0
    movw    r3, #504
.loop1:
    vld1.32 {d0, d1, d2, d3}, [r0]!
    vadd.i32    q8, q0, q8
    vadd.i32    q8, q1, q8
    subs    r3, #8
    bne .loop1
    vpadd.i32   d0, d16, d17
    vpaddl.u32  d0, d0
    vmov.32 r1, d0[0]

    @ InlineAsm End
    str r1, [sp]
    str r0, [sp, #4]
    .loc    18 155 12               @ ...
    ldr r0, [sp]
    .loc    18 155 5 is_stmt 0      @ ...
    add sp, #8
    bx  lr
Ltmp19:
Lfunc_end3:
    .cfi_endproc
```

Comment: Thanks for Paul for editing.  Hope answer or hint how to proceed with be nice.

Comment: Don't you end up doing one more `pld` than you have array?

Comment: If the `pld` is the problem, you should be able to verify that by changing r3 to use #504.  It won't give you the correct answer (since it will skip processing the last entry), but it seems like it would highlight where the problem is.

Comment: After change to #504, I tried both having and not having the pld. Still lldb.

Comment: The assembly code is as follows:

Comment: If that's the same code you edited into your question, please delete those comments.  It's not doing anyone any good in that unreadable form.

Comment: Did you try single-stepping it in a debugger?  That will give you much more information than works/doesn't-work.  And you can add that info to your question.  Do you maybe clobber something you didn't tell the compiler about, so it ends up trying to free the wrong value?  Maybe you can get a clue from looking at what the bogus value is that's passed to `free`.  Actually, is that commented-out `free` line even the one you're talking about?  I don't even know what part of the code you're talking about commenting/un-commenting, or what kind of failure.

Comment: I would try further later, and many thanks for the help. I think it is totally out of  my depth and go back to basic before come back to this question.